# Spring boot + Spring Data JPA + Atomikos + Multiple databases configuration

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-boot, atomikos

With this configuration (MainConfig.java):

```
import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MainConfig {

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "userTransaction")
    public UserTransaction userTransaction() throws Throwable {
        UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
        userTransactionImp.setTransactionTimeout(10000);
        return userTransactionImp;
    }

    @Bean(name = "atomikosTransactionManager", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager() throws Throwable {
        UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
        return userTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @DependsOn({ "userTransaction", "atomikosTransactionManager" })
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Throwable {
        UserTransaction userTransaction = userTransaction();
        TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager = atomikosTransactionManager();
        return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction, atomikosTransactionManager);
    }

}
```

(CustomerConfig.java)

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.at.mul.repository.customer", entityManagerFactoryRef = "customerEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class CustomerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Bean(name = "customerDataSource", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource customerDataSource() {
        MysqlXADataSource mysqlXaDataSource = new MysqlXADataSource();
        mysqlXaDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atomikos_1");
        mysqlXaDataSource.setPinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection(true);
        mysqlXaDataSource.setPassword("password");
        mysqlXaDataSource.setUser("root");
        mysqlXaDataSource.setPinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection(true);

        AtomikosDataSourceBean xaDataSource = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
        xaDataSource.setXaDataSource(mysqlXaDataSource);
        xaDataSource.setUniqueResourceName("xads1");
        return xaDataSource;
    }


    @Bean(name = "customerEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customerEntityManager() throws Throwable {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(customerDataSource());
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan("com.at.mul.domain.customer");
        entityManager.setPersistenceUnitName("customerPersistenceUnit");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "JTA");
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

(OrderConfig.java)

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.at.mul.repository.order", entityManagerFactoryRef = "orderEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class OrderConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Bean(name = "orderDataSource", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource orderDataSource() {
        MysqlXADataSource mysqlXaDataSource = new MysqlXADataSource();
        mysqlXaDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atomikos_2");
        mysqlXaDataSource.setPinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection(true);
        mysqlXaDataSource.setPassword("password");
        mysqlXaDataSource.setUser("root");
        mysqlXaDataSource.setPinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection(true);

        AtomikosDataSourceBean xaDataSource = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
        xaDataSource.setXaDataSource(mysqlXaDataSource);
        xaDataSource.setUniqueResourceName("xads2");
        return xaDataSource;
    }


    @Bean(name = "orderEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean orderEntityManager() throws Throwable {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(orderDataSource());
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan("com.at.mul.domain.order");
        entityManager.setPersistenceUnitName("orderPersistenceUnit");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "JTA");
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

(CustomerRepository.java)

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.at.mul.domain.customer.Customer;

public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

}
```

(OrderRepository.java)

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.at.mul.domain.order.Order;

public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer> {

}
```

I get a NullPointerException on when running this test:

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.at.mul.MainConfig;
import com.at.mul.domain.customer.Customer;
import com.at.mul.repository.customer.CustomerRepository;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MainConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class CustomerRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Test
    public void testCustomerConfig() {

    }

    @Test
    public void save() {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.setName("test-name");
        c.setAge(30);
        Customer cust = customerRepository.save(c);
        Assert.assertNotNull(cust.getId());
    }

}
```

The null object seems to be the transactionManager, so I suppose it's not properly injected. Relevant part of the stacktrace is here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:541)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:285)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:227)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:369)
```

The pom file is here:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC5</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.at.mul</groupId>
    <artifactId>mul-at</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mul-at</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Full code is available on Github: https://github.com/fabiomaffioletti/mul-at I could not find any working example, and even after looking at the [Spring blog article](http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/) I cannot get it to work. Has anyone any hint?

Following the console log of spring boot for the customer connection:

```
2014-04-01 11:29:48.645  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean   : AtomikosDataSoureBean 'xads1': init...
2014-04-01 11:29:48.645  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean   : AtomikosDataSoureBean 'xads1': poolSize equals default - this may cause performance problems!
2014-04-01 11:29:48.672  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean   : AtomikosDataSoureBean 'xads1': initializing with [ xaDataSourceClassName=null, uniqueResourceName=xads1, maxPoolSize=1, minPoolSize=1, borrowConnectionTimeout=30, maxIdleTime=60, reapTimeout=0, maintenanceInterval=60, testQuery=null, xaProperties=[], loginTimeout=0, maxLifetime=0]
2014-04-01 11:29:48.809  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.a.icatch.imp.thread.TaskManager        : THREADS: using JDK thread pooling...
2014-04-01 11:29:48.837  INFO 22368 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'customerPersistenceUnit'
2014-04-01 11:29:48.857  INFO 22368 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: customerPersistenceUnit
    ...]
2014-04-01 11:29:48.919  INFO 22368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
2014-04-01 11:29:48.920  INFO 22368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2014-04-01 11:29:48.922  INFO 22368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2014-04-01 11:29:49.057  INFO 22368 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
2014-04-01 11:29:49.086  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean   : AtomikosDataSoureBean 'xads1': getConnection ( null )...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.087  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean   : AtomikosDataSoureBean 'xads1': init...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.145  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
2014-04-01 11:29:49.145  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: calling getMetaData...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.166  INFO 22368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2014-04-01 11:29:49.172  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
2014-04-01 11:29:49.172  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: calling getCatalog...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.174  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
2014-04-01 11:29:49.175  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: calling getMetaData...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.175  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
2014-04-01 11:29:49.175  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: calling createClob...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.177  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
2014-04-01 11:29:49.177  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: close()...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.258  INFO 22368 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2014-04-01 11:29:49.428  INFO 22368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2014-04-01 11:29:49.428  INFO 22368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2014-04-01 11:29:49.428  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean   : AtomikosDataSoureBean 'xads1': getConnection ( null )...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.428  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean   : AtomikosDataSoureBean 'xads1': init...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.428  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
2014-04-01 11:29:49.428  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: calling getAutoCommit...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.429  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
2014-04-01 11:29:49.429  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: calling getMetaData...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.429  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
2014-04-01 11:29:49.430  WARN 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
2014-04-01 11:29:49.430  INFO 22368 --- [           main] c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  : atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@63f9f0f2: calling createStatement...
2014-04-01 11:29:49.431  INFO 22368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2014-04-01 11:29:49.446  INFO 22368 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: atomikos_1.customer
2014-04-01 11:29:49.446  INFO 22368 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [id, age, name]
2014-04-01 11:29:49.446  INFO 22368 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
2014-04-01 11:29:49.446  INFO 22368 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
2014-04-01 11:29:49.447  INFO 22368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `CMTTransaction` in the stack trace is the clue: Hibernate thinks you are in a container. I also think it might work if you just remove the `javax.persistence.transactionType=JTA` property.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I modified and pushed the modification as you suggested. I don't get the NPE anymore, but the entity is still not persisted. I added the console log to the main post to help identify the problem.

Comment: I can have a closer look if you include a README with precise instructions for creating test databases. Why not go with in-memory for testing?

Comment: Dave, I just pushed the in memory db implementation on the master branch of the github repo. I made another branch called "mysql-db" with a README containing how to create mysql databases.

Comment: Thanks. I can't see anything wrong with it - looks pretty vanilla. If you crank up the logging you can see the transaction saying it is committing, but clearly the entity manager never got the message.

Comment: I can also see something like "atomikos connection proxy for conn7: url=jdbc:h2:order user=: WARNING: transaction manager not running?" which is weird to me. I just put on github a test I made a while ago with a previous version of spring (3.2.3 - no spring-boot, no spring-data-jpa) which involves two databases and activemq and it seems to work well. Unfortunately I don't have an in memory implementation for this one, but you can see the code here: https://github.com/fabiomaffioletti/mul-at-spring-3 Do you have any other suggestion to give me?

Comment: I don't know really. We can chat if you like: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/50400/atomikos-spring-data-jpa-issue?tab=general

Comment: I would, but I have no enough reputation to write on it

Comment: Sorry, I added you to the chat, but you need 20 reps. It's easy to get that.

Comment: The `WARNING: transaction manager not running?` was due to the fact that the transactionManager was not created before the Customer/OrderConfig (I read that this can happen using @ComponentScan annotations). I solved it by declaring those two classes dependant on the transactionManager bean. `@DependsOn("transactionManager")`. But the entityManager still does not get notified. BTW I have enough reputation to write on the chat now.

Comment: See http://goo.gl/jpmZ0f for the solution coming from this discussion and the chat.

Answer (score -1):

Ofcource, you can remove `javax.persistence.transactionType=JTA`
and it will work.

But if you want to use JBOSS AS with own transaction manager (i like it more; there is a some bugs in atomicos which has fixed only customer version), you must put:

```
transactionType=JTA
```

Into persistance.xml  property:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                      value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
```

Into spring-config:

```
<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Answer (score -2):

https://blog.hanqunfeng.com/2016/12/21/spring-boot-study-jpa/#more

```java
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
@DependsOn({"atomikosJtaPlatfom"}) // need to register atomikosJtaPlatfom first
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    System.out.println("entityManagerFactory init");
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    // entity package
    entityManager.setPackagesToScan("com.example.model.ds1");
    entityManager.setJtaDataSource(dataSource());
    Properties properties = new Properties();       
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    // JTA setting
    properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "jta");
    properties.put("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory");
    // here we specify the AtomikosJtaPlatfom we created ourselves
    properties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform","com.example.AtomikosJtaPlatfom");
    entityManager.setJpaProperties(properties);
    return entityManager;
}
```